# how do i start everything over with django?

Tags: python, django

I've been working with django recently as a beginner and I was struggling with how to learn django and I messed everything up so I decided I should start over  I tried to uninstall django and install it again but nothing worked I tried to make a new directory on my windows and still nothing worked is there anyway to reset my installation and restart my whole software?

Here's how I started learning:

1. I went to youtube and followed a free course and followed along with it
2. I then downloaded a book from a website and tried to follow along with it with my old project then i finally took the decision to delete everything
3. I don't know how to restart all my work
4. tried to uninstall django and work with a new project but it keeps giving me errors .
5. tried to delete all the files from my last project didn't work
6. tried to move my old files to new directory didn't work
7. tried to delete all code contained in the old project's files get screwed
   what do I do guys? I'm clearly crying in the bathroom with my laptop with me please help

Comment: There's no need to swear; I do it plenty in RL but it's not something you'd want on, say, wikipedia. Also, this has nothing to do with your django installation

Comment: well, thanks i guess?

Comment: You're welcome. Downvotes and close votes will count against your account and, very quickly, you'll be banned from asking questions. I have used django a bit, it's just a case of opening a terminal in a new directory and starting a new app, no?

Comment: To preserve progress, you should take a look at [`git`](https://git-scm.com/).  It allows you to save as many backups of your code as you want without consuming a  ton of space.  It is the de-facto source control system for software engineers these days.  That said, you've basically told us, "It's broke."  Without specifics it is hard to know what your issue is.  Perhaps start back at the beginning with `python django-admin.py startproject` ?

Comment: hey guys, i was checking out was wrong and i found the answer the real problem was that  i was using too much disk space (only 92 kb left.) so i had to delete some programs i usually when i start a django project i import all the virtualenv into my project folder so icould activate and deactivate my virtualenv easily so i deleted some programs and i'm good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your django project is using a different version than the one installed on your computer.

This issue happened to me when I updated django using pip, only to find out that my django project is no longer compatible. I had to find out which version my project was using and I reinstalled it.

First make sure that the version of your project matches the version of django that is installed.